# gpucompute* is down* in slurm cluster

Tags: gpu, nvidia, slurm, sbatch, sysinfo

There is a down state on my gpucompute nodes and cant send the jobs on GPU nodes.
I couldn't return my 'down GPU' nodes after following all the solutions on the net. Before this problem, I had an error with the Nvidia driver configuration in a way that I couldn't detect the GPUs by 'nvidia-smi', after solving that error by running 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.79.run --no-drm' I have encountered this error that is because of the down state of the nodes. Appreciate very much any help!

```
command: sbatch md1.s
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available

command:  sinfo
PARTITION   AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
gpucompute*    up   infinite      1  down* fwb-lab-tesla1

command:  sinfo -R
REASON               USER      TIMESTAMP           NODELIST
Not responding       slurm     2020-09-25T13:13:19 fwb-lab-tesla1

 command: sinfo -Nl
Fri Sep 25 16:35:25 2020
NODELIST        NODES   PARTITION       STATE CPUS    S:C:T MEMORY TMP_DISK WEIGHT AVAIL_FE REASON              
fwb-lab-tesla1      1 gpucompute*       down*   32   32:1:1  64000        0      1   (null)Not responding 


command: vim /etc/slurm/slurm.conf
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=FWB-Lab-Tesla
#ControlAddr=137.72.38.102
#
MailProg=/bin/mail
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
#SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmdUser=root
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/StateSave
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
#
#
# TIMERS
#KillWait=30

command: ls /etc/init.d
functions  livesys  livesys-late  netconsole  network  README

command: nvidia-smi
Fri Sep 25 16:35:01 2020    

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 24%   32C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB / 12036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   35C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB / 12036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB / 12036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  TITAN V             Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   42C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB / 12036MiB |      6%      Default |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved with the below instructions. Remember that you need to enter the commands after reboot anytime you restart the system. Thanks to Joan Bryan for resolving this!

```
slurmd -Dcvvv
reboot
ps -ef | grep slurm
kill xxxx (this is Process id number in the output of previous ps ef command)
nvidia-smi
systemctl start slurmctld
systemctl start slurmd
scontrol update nodename=fwb-lab-tesla1 state=idle

now you can run the jobs on the GPU nodes!
Cheers
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned probably prevented the `slurmd` daemon on `gpucompute` from  starting. You should be able to confirm that by running `systemctl status slurmd`  or the equivalent command for your Linux distribution.

The `slurmd` logs probably contain a line similar to

```
slurmd[1234]: fatal: can't stat gres.conf file /dev/nvidia0: No such file or directory
```

Try restarting it with

```
systemctl start slurmd
```

once you made sure `nvidia-smi` responded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this command. nvidia-smi responded correctly. Although something has changed but still, cannot send the job on the node;

`sinfo`
`gpucompute*    up   infinite      1   unk* fwb-lab-tesla1`


`sinfo -Nl `        
`fwb-lab-tesla1      1 gpucompute*    unknown*   32   32:1:1  64000        0      1   (null) none`

`sbatch md1.s`
`sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available`

Comment: after a while, it turned to down* again.
`gpucompute*       down* `

Comment: It seems its state changes continuously. it is in drained and low real memory state :

`sinfo`
`gpucompute*    up   infinite      1  drain fwb-lab-tesla1`

 `sinfo -Nl`             
`fwb-lab-tesla1      1 gpucompute*     drained   32   32:1:1  64000        0      1   (null) Low RealMemory  `
    
`sinfo -R`
`Low RealMemory       root      2020-09-27T10:52:38 fwb-lab-tesla1`

Comment: the final state is down* again.

Comment: `systemctl status slurmd`
`Active: active (running)
Can't open PID file /var/run/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start: No ...ctory`

Comment: It seems there is a mismatch between where Systemd is configured to look for the `.pid` file (`/var/run/slurmd.pid`) and where Slurm is configured to write it. Look at the `SlurmdPidFile` parameter in `slurm.conf`

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
`SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
....#SlurmctldPort=6817
.....SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
.....#SlurmdPort=6818
.....SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
.....#SlurmUser=slurm
....SlurmdUser=root`


 `cat slurmctld.pid 
1505
 ....cat slurmd.pid 
2919
 ....pwd
/var/run`

Comment: However, sometimes the `slurmd.pid` is gone and there is not in the `/var/run/` path so there is below error as well:
`Active : Failed` and
`slurmd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1` and
`Failed to start Slurm node daemon.` and
`Unit slurmd.service entered failed state.` and 
`slurmd.service failed.` Anyway in both states of absence or presence of slurmd.pid I can't run any job since the node state is down or drained respectively.